# Primefaces dropdown size overflowing based on value size

Tags: primefaces, size, dropdown

I am using primefaces selectOneMenu and my dropdown size is overflowing my panel.

I have given a max-width of 280px but it is taking the default size of dropdown value which is 330px as min-width 330px.

I want to use size for dropdown as 280px and when i select the dropdown i want to show the values with 330px.

How i do i fix this. Please help fixing this issue.

Comment: Start by creating a [mcve] like requested in [ask]. Maybe provide screensshots and provide version info. And play with a client-side developertool to manipulate the CSS.